# UICollectionViewCell will be displayed/ was displayed?

Tags: xcode, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

pretty simple question.

Is there a notification or delegate-type method to tell when a UICollectionViewCell object is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 5:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        super.collectionView(collectionView, willDisplay: cell, forItemAt: indexPath)
         // Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

For iOS 8 and higher you can use *willDisplayCell* of *UICollectionViewDelegate*

`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Being as iOS 8 is the current release, I'll mark this as correct. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't actually tell if it's displayed on screen or not. Cell might be added off screen also. From the documentation: _The collection view calls this method before adding a cell to its content. Use this method to detect cell additions, as opposed to monitoring the cell itself to see when it appears._

Comment: this works for me. It gets called every time the cell comes back in view as I scroll it off and in the view... running iOS 13

Comment: it is called before cell will be displayed, not after it displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Will:

[`-[<UICollectionViewDataSource> collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012175-CH1-SW4)

Did:

[`-[<UICollectionViewDelegate> collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012176-CH1-SW16)

Comment: @Dave DeLong: didEndDisplayingCell refers to the cell being *removed* from the collection view. From the Apple docs "Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the collection view."

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: Actually `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will be called even if some cells were recycled. It's up to you to decide if you want to reuse recycled cell or create a new one inside this method.